# getting json data that is inside a bracket

Tags: python, json

I have been using rapid api to get some data on certain food products and below is an example of the json data i got back. I have been able to get some data such as the ingredients and but
where i am struggling is getting the data that are nested inside each other. My question is how would i be able to get for example the data of "amount" which is inside nutrients in python.

```
"ingredients": "Whole Grain Corn, Sugar, Corn Syrup, Corn Meal"


"nutrition": {
    "nutrients": [
        {
            "name": "Calcium",
            "amount": 100.0,
            "unit": "mg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 10.0
        },
        {
            "name": "Carbohydrates",
            "amount": 23.0,
            "unit": "g",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 7.67
        },
```

The way which i was able to get the ingredients was by doing this which worked and printed out the ingredients

```
ingredients = response.json().get("ingredients")
```

But how would i do the same thing to get data inside nutrients?

Comment: Did you try `get("nutrition")`? Then where were you stuck after that?

Comment: Those brackets are just a lists, so you can access individual dictionaries within using indexing or list comprehension. `[nutrient.get("name") for nutrient in data.get("nutrition", {}).get("nutrients")]`.

Comment: get("nutrition") just returns all of the data in raw text format whereas i just want to access  a specific attribute such as "amount" or "name" @OneCricketeer

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Comment: Right, it returns all the data because you need to keep going. My point was that you seem to understand how to get one level of data, and each level returns a new object. You started with a dictionary (not JSON), and getting `nutrition` is another dictionary, so think of it as your new "top level object", and call `.get()` again and again, until you get the data you want (once you get to an array, though, you will need a loop or list-indexing)

Answer (score 2):

It returns a dictionary, but you can use the default return on `dict.get` to avoid any attribute errors:

```py
nutrients = response.json().get('nutrition', {}).get('nutrients')
```

This way, if `nutrition` isn't there, you won't get something like `NoneType has no attribute 'get'`

EDIT:
Now, `nutrients` should probably be a `list` here, so to get each element:

```py
for nutrient in nutrients:
    print(nutrient['name'])
```

To collect them all in a `list`, you could do:

```py
nutrient_names = [nutrient['name'] for nutrient in nutrients]
```

This still assumes that the `name` key is always present for each nutrient. To avoid errors that may result from `nutrient` returning `None`, you could do:

```py
# add an empty list as a default return
nutrients = response.json().get('nutrition', {}).get('nutrients', [])

nutrient_names = [nutrient['name'] for nutrient in nutrients]
```

Comment: so if i was to try and get the "name" (Carbohydrates) in the second pair of brackets how will i format this

Comment: This is what I was saying in the comments @RyanHuddart20. In this answer, after this code there is a variable `nutrients` that is a list. So to get the name from the second one, you could simply `nutrients[1]["name"]`, or `nutrients[1].get("name")`.